# Error writing and reading bitmap to and from temporary cache file android?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Here is my code when I am writing to the file

```
Bitmap bitmap;
InputStream is;

try
{
    is = (InputStream) new URL(myUrl).getContent();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();

     //program crashing here
    File f = File.createTempFile(myUrl,null,MyApplication.getAppContext().getCacheDir());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    bitmap = null;
}
```

And here is my code reading from the same file

```
Bitmap bitmap;
try
{
    File f = new File(myUrl);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    byte[] bitmapArr = new byte[bis.available()];
    bis.read(bitmapArr);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapArr, 0, bitmapArr.length);
    bis.close();
    fis.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    bitmap = null;
}
```

The program is crashing at the creation of the temp file in the first chunk of code.

EDIT: I am getting a libcore.io.ErrnoException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found the problem and fixed it, for anyone interested see below.

I changed it to use the openFileOutput(String, int), and openFileInput(String) methods, I should have done it this way right from the beginning.

The following is working code to decode an input stream from a url containing an image into a bitmap, compress the bitmap and store it into a file, and to retrieve said bitmap from that file later.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
InputStream is;

try
{
    is = (InputStream) new URL(myUrl).getContent();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();

    String filename = "file"
    FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    bitmap = null;
}
```

and

```
Bitmap bitmap;

try
{
    String filename = "file";
    FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput(filename);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    fis.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    bitmap = null;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answering your own question, but calling openFileOutput() with Context.MODE_PRIVATE will not create the file in the application's cache directory.